# linux: cannot use kill with verbose

Tags: linux, bash, kill

I try to find a list of processes and kill them using verbose option, but not successful.

```
$ kill --verbose -9 $(ps -eo pid,cmd | grep cmd_name | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }')
bash: kill: -verbose: invalid signal specification
```

Then I try to put '-9' in front.

```
$ kill -9 --verbose $(ps -eo pid,cmd | grep cmd_name | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }')
bash: kill: --verbose: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

If I don't use verbose, it seems working fine. But I like to use verbose here if possible.

BTW, I am using RHEL 8 and this is part of [the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html).

```
       --verbose
              Print  PID(s)  that  will  be  signaled with kill
              along with the signal.
```

Comment: The man page doesn’t list that flag https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html

Comment: `kill` does not have a `--verbose` option. And `--verbose` is indeed not a valid signal (unlike `-9`, or `-KILL`)

Comment: check my new edit

Comment: Aside: `grep cmd_name | grep -v grep` is long and buggy, use `grep '[c]md_name'` instead BUT you never need grep when you're using awk so that whole pipeline should just be `ps -eo pid,cmd | awk '/[c]md_name/{ print $1 }'` if you don't have `pkill` (thanks @JohnKugelman for the reminder!).

Comment: There's a `pkill` command that kills processes by name. Use that. All this `ps | grep | grep -v grep` stuff is so ancient.

Comment: Does pkill have something like verbose? I scan through man page and haven't found one. If I kill 10 processes, I need to record their PID's.

Comment: @EdMorton, This is a part of script. In real script, cmd_name is supplied by $1. How to apply [ and ] in such case?

Comment: You don't need to since the string `cmd_name`, which you're using in grep or awk, won't be present in the `ps` output, whatever `$1` is set to will be.

Comment: If you want to print the PID before killing the process then just write a wrapper, e.g. `vkill() { echo "$*"; kill "$@"; }` or similar.

Comment: If you are using `bash`, `kill` is a built-in command, with these forms: `kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] [pid | jobspec] ...` and `kill -l|-L [sigspec | exit_status]`. No `--verbose`. See [`man bash`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#:~:text=its%20exit%20status.-,kill%20%5B%2Ds,-sigspec%20%7C%20%2Dn). Use `env kill ...` instead of `kill ...` if you want to use the OS one.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `pkill` command that kills processes by name. Use that. All this `ps | grep | grep -v grep` stuff is so ancient.
<sub>(I'm not shaming you. I want to alert people who find this question on Google.)</sub>

```
pkill cmd_name
```

It doesn't have an option to both print and kill at the same time. If you want to also print the PIDs being killed you could leverage its companion command `pgrep`:

```
pgrep cmd_name | xargs --verbose kill
```